# What is the name for the hole in the head of a screw?

Tags: single-word-requests

Sure, the screw itself would be a "phillips head" or a "flat head" screw, but what would you call the hole in the head? Surely "phillips head hole" or "flat head hole" just doesn't seem right - **is there a technical word for "the thing which you insert a screwdriver bit into on the face of a screw head?"**

Every resource I can find just talks about types of "screw heads", which is great, but in a field with as many technical words as assembly, I feel like there must be a name for this whole class of specially-shaped holes.

Comment: It's generally called a "slot", even for Philips-head screws.  People do puzzle about Allen-head screws, though.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_screw_drives

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called the drive of the screw or a screw drive.

Source: https://www.wonkeedonkeetools.co.uk/screws/what-are-the-parts-of-a-screw